# Me salen barras iguales al intentar modificar el eje en ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Modifiqué el eje, para que en lugar de los conteos me muestre los porcentajes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)
uno = c(3337,998)
calif = c("paso","no paso")

df = data.frame(calif,uno)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = calif, y=..count../sum(..count..), fill = calif)) + 
  guides(fill=FALSE, color=FALSE) + 
  ggtitle("Distribución de notas para estudiantes que tomaron Precálculo la primera vez") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + scale_x_discrete("Nota")  +
  geom_bar()+scale_y_continuous(labels=percent, limits = c(0,.95),("Porcentaje")) +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)
```

Sin embargo, solo me salen dos barras iguales.

Comment: Por favor, lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Es razonable que sean dos barras del mismo tamaño, esto: `..count../sum(..count..)` siempre es `1`. También son algo extraños los datos desde dónde partes, pareciera que es una estadística completamente precalculada, no es lo más habitual, pero claro, puede también graficarse con `ggplot`, simplemente precalcularía también el porcentaje:

```
df$porc <- df$uno/sum(df$uno)
```

Y, claro no podemos usar `stat="count"`  sino `stat="identity"` ya que justamente viene todo precalculado:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(calif), y=porc, fill = calif)) + 
  guides(fill=FALSE, color=FALSE) + 
  ggtitle("Distribución de notas para estudiantes que tomaron Precálculo la primera vez") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_x_discrete("Nota")  +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(stat='identity', aes(label=round(porc,2)), vjust=-1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]